# flexbox html5 video fill remaining space

Tags: html, css, html5-video, flexbox

I try to have a html5 video that fills the remaining space in a flexbox div.

However, it overflows rather than doing what I want:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <video src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" />
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pwhwL29p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a video and a footer inside the `.wrapper` element. The `height: 100%` on the video may or may not work, depending on the browser (more details below).

Since you don't have a height defined on the `.content` element, which holds the video, the results are unpredictable and unreliable. Again, browser behavior varies.

Here's a method that is more efficient and reliable across browsers:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  display: flex; /* NEW */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; <-- REMOVE; not necessary */
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">
 <video src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" />
 </div>
  <div class="footer">footer </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pwhwL29p/2/)

Here's how it works:

- Turn the `.content` flex item, which contains the video, into a flex container.
- This activates `align-items: stretch`, a default setting, which makes the video consume all available space in the cross-axis (in this case, height).
- Remove `height: 100%`. Flex layout handles height dynamically.

More details:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

---

### UPDATE

From the comments:

> Thank you. it works great for the standard video tag. Unfortunately it breaks with video.js

The video script adds a container to the HTML structure:

[image]

As a result, the function of the  `.content` flex container no longer works.

You'll need to make adjustments to the CSS. Add this:

```
#video {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwhwL29p/8/)

Comment: Thank you. it works great for the standard video tag. Unfortunately it breaks with video.js --> http://jsfiddle.net/pwhwL29p/6/